# How to disable line highlight in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

Look at how awful this looks:

[image]

It's very hard to read on the line you're actually working on.

Is there a way to disable this highlighting feature?

Comment: You can also change the color.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have the "[Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)" extension installed it's an option:

[image: power tools options screen]

Otherwise:

> Tools / Options / Environment Section / Fonts and Colors / Current Line

Answer (score 3):

Tools / Options / expand the environment section / Fonts and Colors / Current Line - change the background from Default to ... dark gray (or whatever that color is you are using; it doesn't look like pure black to me ...)